# Qual padrão devemos utilizar para criar tags?

Tags: debate, tags

Quando temos tags no estilo

- [image-compression](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-compression)
- [google-chrome-extension](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension)

Qual o modo mais apropriado para utilizá-las em português?

1. [imagem-compressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagem-compress%c3%a3o)
2. [compressão-imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compress%c3%a3o-imagem)
3. [compressão-de-imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compress%c3%a3o-de-imagem)
4. [compressão-imagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compress%c3%a3o-imagens)
5. [compressão-de-imagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compress%c3%a3o-de-imagens)