# Precisamos de padronização para tags com mais de uma palavra?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, tags, big-7, padronização

Reparei que as novas tags (no momento podendo ser criadas por qualquer usuário), quando as mesmas possuem mais de uma palavra, não costumam seguir um padrão único, sendo escritas de diversas formas diferentes:

- Palavras juntas

  [integracaocontinua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integracaocontinua) [querystring](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/querystring) [openhardwaremonitor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openhardwaremonitor) [androidstudio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/androidstudio)
- Palavras separadas por hífen (com preposição)

  [banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/banco-de-dados) [envio-de-email](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envio-de-email) [lado-do-servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lado-do-servidor) [valor-por-extenso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valor-por-extenso)
- Palavras separadas por hífen (sem preposição)

  [tela-tamanho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tela-tamanho) [aprendizagem-programacão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aprendizagem-programac%c3%a3o)
- Conceito hífen subconceito

  [formulário-submeter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formul%c3%a1rio-submeter) [índice-único](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%c3%adndice-%c3%banico) [restrição-único](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restri%c3%a7%c3%a3o-%c3%banico) [simplexml-load-string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplexml-load-string) [url-reescrever](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-reescrever) [html-table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table)
- Subconceito hífen conceito

  [tabela-banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela-banco-de-dados)

Os mais comuns, pelo que pude observar, foram o "palavras juntas", "palavras separadas por hífen com preposição [se aplicável]", e "conceito hífen subconceito".

É necessário criar alguma padronização para os nomes de tags? Ou talvez sugerir sinônimos para as mesmas? Ou deixamos tudo como está?

(E se a resposta anterior for "precisa fazer algo", o que posso fazer para ajudar? Retagear, por exemplo? E é bom lembrar que muitas das tags existentes ainda sofrem com o [bug do cedilha](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/279/por-que-alguns-caracteres-nao-funcionam-em-tags), uma vez que o mesmo já estiver resolvido no site principal - já está? - algo precisará ser feito em relação a essas tags também...)

Comment: Eu ficaria entre a 2 e 3 apenas, embora eu consiga ver um pequeno motivo, não muito bom, o para usar a 1. Muita boa questão. E é um dilema p/ nomear qualquer coisa em programação também. Nossa língua não é boa para isso.

Comment: Eu acho estranho cortar a preposição "de", mas tem a vantagem de ficar mais curto. Entre singular e plural, por mim tanto faz, contanto que usemos sempre o mesmo padrão. E acho que vamos precisar de sinônimos.

Comment: Eu acho que a opção `3` seria a mais legível. Mas ela perde a ideia de ser `compressão` dentro de `imagem`, parece o inverso. (Pensando como um namespace)

Comment: Eu acho que a opção 5 está extensa porém é a de mais fácil compreensão.

Comment: Tudojuntoficamuitodifícildeler, não acha?

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo 100%, apenas apontei que é um formato comum. Na minha opinião, esse é um caso onde uma intervenção seria bem-vinda. Exceto nos casos em que faz sentido manter junto (ex.: "arraylist", se referindo à classe `ArrayList`), creio que é melhor separar por hífen.

Comment: Eu não achei que você pensasse diferente, mas não resisti a deixar um comentário divertido. Deveria ter dito "não acham" no final :) Sobre a duplicação, se esta for fechada seria bom se as duas fossem fundidas, aqui a discussão avançou mais.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, creio que uma fusão/mesclagem (*merge*) seria boa. A pergunta linkada levanta outro ponto, que é o singular/plural, não tinha reparado nisso quando fiz essa listinha.

Comment: Estou a votar para reabrir pois esta pergunta cobre um assunto diferente da qual foi marcada como duplicada de... Podem ser semelhantes, mas a estrutura das tags e a tradução dos termos são duas coisas distintas.

Answer (score 10):

Ótimo temos muitas coisas para definir sobre as tags e o momento para evitar desastres no futuro, é agora.

Elas devem ser separadas por hífen sempre (ou quase).

Existem alguns casos que uma palavra composta virou única. Pode ser nome próprio (ex.: [extjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extjs)) ou algum termo, principalmente em inglês. Um caso típico é QueryString. Este é uma caso se alguém achar melhor separar, eu não me oporia já que o hífen padronizaria tudo, mas é algo que é usado junto com frequência. poderíamos analisar essas casos individualmente. Embora o exemplo é o contrário, o correto é [sql-server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) e não `sqlserver`, já que o nome é separado.

Como agora, aceita acentos e acho que devemos trocar as tags enquanto ainda está em private, devemos aproveitar e mudar esses casos.

[Nessa questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/130/qual-padrao-devemos-utilizar-para-criar-tags) começamos discutir isso mas não foi muito pra frente. Devemos resolver isso já.

Acho que a preposição deve ser usada para dar mais sentido e fluidez. Pessoalmente eu gosto das coisas mais curtas mesmo que fique subentendido, mas vou decidir contra minha vontade aqui. A não ser, é claro, que os demais achem que o curto, sem preposição, seja melhor.

Para pegar um outro exemplo, a tag [tamanho-tela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tamanho-tela) provavelmente foi criada da tradução literal `screen-size` mas acho que o correto deveria ser [tamanho-de-tela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tamanho-de-tela) ou [tamanho-tela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tamanho-tela) se ficar decidido que a preposição deve ser deixada fora. Vamos traduzir do jeito mais correto possível. E [url-reescrever](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-reescrever) deveria ser [tag:url:reescrita]. Pode ser uma diferença cultural. Se for, devemos manter as duas formas (ou três, se contar a [url-rewrite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-rewrite) que é um termo bem conhecido]) como sinônimos ou deixar apenas uma?

[tabela-banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela-banco-de-dados) Se não me engano foi criada por mim. Fiquei muito na dúvida e quase abri uma pergunta aqui. Fiquei entre essa, [tabela-de-banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela-de-banco-de-dados) e [banco-de-dados-tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/banco-de-dados-tabela). Como o mgibsonbr, destacou bem, existem diferenças. Qual é a correta?

Precisamnos definir quando usar o conceito solto e quando usar conceito e sub-conceito. Por exemplo: [tags](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) está bom ou deveria ser [html-tags](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-tags)? As duas devem existir e manter sinônimos?

Um caso que pode estar errado (por isso não criei descrição para ela): [normalizacão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalizac%c3%a3o). A tag foi usada como [normalização-de-banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-banco-de-dados) ou [normalização-banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-banco-de-dados) ou [banco-de-dados-normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/banco-de-dados-normaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o). A palavra normalização sozinha pode ser normalização numérica. Vamos permitir o uso dela isolada? Será sinônimo de alguma outra com mais contexto?

Outro problema específico: [consulta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consulta). Parece genérica de mais. Essa eu já afirmo que está errada. Deveria haver contexto. No SO original sempre tem contexto. O que acham?

Tem algumas tags que eu acho que simplesmente não deveriam existir. Eu não fiz a descrição de várias delas por causa disto.

[.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tem ponto, [htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) deveria ter também?

[503](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/503) Não deveria ser [erro-503](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro-503) ou mesmo [error-503](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error-503)? 503 pode até não dar margem para outra interpretação mas outros erros podem.

[vetores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vetores), [vector](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vector), [array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) me parecem ser conceitos diferentes e estão corretamente separados. Alguém acha que devem ser sinônimos?

Singular e plural deve ser sinônimo, certo?

**Resumindo** esses pontos, minha sugestão é: usar hífen para separar palavras realmente separadas, preposição para dar fluidez, exceto(?) em sub-conceito que deve vir depois do conceito principal.

Alguma ideia diferente, melhor?

Outro ponto não levantado é que devemos aceitar alguns casos de uso da tag em inglês também e criar sinônimo. As tags nas duas línguas faz sentido para facilitar a busca. Acho que deve ser incentivado. Se houver polêmico, abrirei uma pergunta para esse item específico.

Aproveito aqui para levantar algo relevante não tão relacionada. Algumas tags estão sendo descritas de forma incorreta para o contexto. E a edição sendo aprovada. Um exemplo: [spliterator](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spliterator). Está falando de PHP e a tag foi usada em Java. E as buscas no Google retornam basicamente links sobre Java. [self](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self) é outro exemplo. A linguagem deveria ser [linguagem-self](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linguagem-self). Tem outro caso que eu acho que foi rejeitado, onde a descrição de OOP remetia ao uso específico do PHP. Esse é um dos problemas de ainda estarmos em private. Algumas pessoas sem muita consciência, experiência e que não participam do meta estão podendo aprovar essas coisas.

Vamos dar uma olhada no original para ver como eles resolveram. Não podemos fazer pior. Lá tem muitos erros, mas estamos criando alguns erros aqui que lá está bem solucionado.

Vamos aproveitar e tentar achar outros problemas.

Se não forem contra, vou começar em breve arrumar esses casos, de acordo com as regras definidas, aproveitando para acertar os acentos. Acho que as tags sem acentos devem ser excluídas. Vou fazer na ordem cronológica para tentar manter ativas por último as questões mais novas (claro que aquelas que não tem problemas nessas tags, vão ficar para trás, mas a não fará muita diferença para a maioria. Todos podem ajudar nas questões existentes e sempre que surgir novas questões com problemas de tags.

Comment: Sobre "spliterator" e "self", devemos definir a tag para o termo mais comum, e criar outras (como php-spl e php-iterator) para os menos comuns.

Comment: Sobre "querystring", creio que o correto seria separar por hífen mesmo. Se você procurar "query string" na wikipédia, encontrará um artigo dessa forma, separado. Contraste "arraylist", que é uma classe específica cujo nome é sempre escrito junto (`ArrayList` no original - camel case).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Até **concordo**, mas no SO está junto então acaba gerando uma certa dúvida. Não estou dizendo que devemos seguir tudo o que está lá, porque tem erros.

Comment: Sobre "normalização", não sei se é necessário uma intervenção agora, se deixa pra depois ou se seria impraticável fazer depois. Assim como "self", embora o nome possua um caráter genérico, isso não quer dizer que essa tag será usada de modo genérico. Se a maioria dos usos de "normalização" se refere ao BD, e a maioria dos usos de "self" se refere à linguagem, apenas as exceções deveriam usar tags mais específicas IMHO.

Comment: E quanto a ".net" e "htaccess", imagino que assim mesmo esteja bom. O ponto faz parte do nome "Dot Net", dizer apenas "net" não faz o menor sentido... Mas "htaccess" é o nome de um arquivo, que por acaso começa com um ponto, ou seja: o ponto é um detalhe técnico, não faz parte da **indentidade** do conceito.

Answer (score 10):

Deixar todas as palavras juntas sou totalmente contra, fica ilegível. Quanto a colocar subconceito antes de conceito, prefiro o contrário, na maioria dos casos.

Estou achando complicado termos uma padronização muito rígida, parece que depende. Tem casos em que a variante com preposição poderia ser substituída pelo formato conceito-subconceito, mas é provável que diferentes pessoas prefiram de uma ou outra maneira.

Minha opinião sobre alguns dos exemplos:

- [banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/banco-de-dados)
  Me parece ok. Sem o "de" ficaria muito estranho.
- [envio-de-email](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envio-de-email)
  Esta funciona como conceito-subconceito, poderia ser [email-envio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email-envio). As duas opções soam bem para mim
- [lado-do-servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lado-do-servidor)
  Merece um sinônimo [server-side](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side), em português soa tão esquisito!
- [valor-por-extenso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valor-por-extenso)
  A preposição aqui é obrigatória, senão o sentido muda.
- [tela-tamanho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tela-tamanho)
  Soa estranho, "tela" não parece ter força suficiente para eu considerar um conceito. Eu usaria [tamanho-de-tela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tamanho-de-tela).
- [aprendizagem-programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aprendizagem-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o)
  Aqui sim soa bem como conceito-subconceito, e como é comprida vale a pena cortar o "de".
- [formulário-submeter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formul%c3%a1rio-submeter)
  Meu problema com esta é de tradução. Eu ficaria confortável com [formulário-submit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formul%c3%a1rio-submit), e acho que [formulário-envio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formul%c3%a1rio-envio) ou [envio-de-formulário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envio-de-formul%c3%a1rio) soam melhor.
- [url-reescrever](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-reescrever)
  Prefiro [url-rewrite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-rewrite), como em [simplexml-load-string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplexml-load-string).
- [tabela-banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela-banco-de-dados)
  Aqui parece bom ter o subconceito primeiro, já que "banco de dados" é muito genérico para definir o assunto de uma pergunta. Poderia ser sinônimo de [tabela-bd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela-bd).

Acho que precisaríamos criar vários sinônimos para deixar as tags bem organizadas e fáceis de usar. Mas a ferramenta atrapalha, pois **só dá para criar sinônimos se ambas as tags já existirem no site, e se o criador tiver pelo menos 5 pontos ou mais na tag em questão**.

Não sei se moderadores têm mais privilégios, mas mesmo se tiverem parece não ser uma boa tarefa para o Gabe, que já tem muito o que fazer.

Comment: Eu concordo que não é algo simples, mas acho que devemos ter um padrão, mesmo que não agrade a maioria e que nem sempre ele seja seguido. Eu acho que taxonomia correta é uma das coisas mais importantes que precisamos impor (democraticamente) ao site. Onde tem mais de uma que parece correta, acho que a solução é simples: aceita-se ambas e coloca sinônimo. Devamos cortar a preposição porque a tag fica longa? É um bom motivo? (Eu até gosto, mas não sei se deve ter exceção). Só reafirmo que nos casos de tradução esquisita, sinônimo é a solução. Porque alguns casos o sub-conceito deve vir primeiro?

Comment: Sinônimos podem ser criados pelos moderadores quando tivermos outros definidos. Sinônimos não são tão urgentes, eles podem ser criados a qualquer momento sem criar problemas. Retag precisa ser já. (editei minha resposta p/ cobrir novos itens)

Comment: Sobre o subconceito-conceito, veja o último exemplo que comentei. bd-tabela parece muito artificial em português, não é como as pessoas tenderiam a usar a tag. @bigown

Comment: Aí não seria melhor usar tabela-de-banco-de-dados? Não que seja a minha opinião. Estou provocando a discussão.

Comment: Sobre ter um padrão, eu não discordo, só acho que precisa haver uma certa flexibilidade. Tem casos ambíguos em que uma tag pode ser entendida como um termo composto ou como conceito-subconceito. Duvido que alguém tente usar dados-banco em vez de banco-de-dados, mas aprendizagem-programação e email-envio já dão margem a duas variantes. Nesses casos, qual seria a principal, e qual seria o sinônimo, @bigown?

Comment: Argh, sou a favor de encurtar quando possível. tabela-de-banco-de-dados eu não gosto.

Comment: Os casos específicos de sinônimos poderão ser discutidos depois. Provavelmente a maioria serão feitos por moderadores e só em casos que fique claro um erro ou os moderadores tenham dúvidas, vamos precisar discutir. O que precisamos é ter uma linha geral do que deve ser sinônimo e acho que o principal ponto é extra além do critério adotado no SO (termos semelhantes, que são intercambiáveis devem ser sinônimos) é que devemos ter o termo em inglês como sinônimo também. A não ser que não tenha tradução, o inglês deve ser secundário. Certo?

Comment: @bigown Acho bom termos sinônimos em inglês em muitos casos. E acho até que o termo em inglês pode ser a tag principal quando o termo for mais usado em inglês, mesmo que haja tradução (exemplo: array, e talvez loop, que já discuti em [outro post](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/165/traducao-de-vocabulario-tecnico-em-ingles/198#198))

Comment: Outro caso de sinônimo necessário é quando o termo soa diferente para brasileiros e portugueses (ou outras nacionalidades).

Comment: Para facilitar criar sinônimos, seria válido ir criando as tags sinônimas nessa mudança que vamos proceder agora para depois poder relacioná-las? Por exemplo, já vi uma boa oportunidade em: http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1756/front-end-access-no-servidor

Comment: Mas aí você incluiria as duas na pergunta? ms-access e microsoft-access?

Comment: Pensei no frontend e backend que já tem tags similares :) Mas foi só um exemplo. A questão é se sempre que acharmos um caso, seria legal fazer isso para irmos dando as opções em inglês para os termos.

Comment: Ah! Acho que vale, @bigown

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui encontrar fonte confiável para uma regra gramatical que esclareça o ponto.

Mas [aqui](http://www.cnpq.br/documents/10157/186158/TabeladeAreasdoConhecimento.pdf) temos uma tabela oficial do CNPQ com o nome de algumas áreas. O que eu percebi é que, temos "Máquinas de Fluxo" e "Processamento de Sinais Biológicos", por exemplo.

Qual a regra para que não seja:

"Maquina de Fluxos" ou "Processamentos de Sinal Biológico" eu não sei.

Acredito que manter as preposições garantirá legibilidade das tags, ainda que fiquem 4 caracteres mais longas.
Imagino que em caso de confusão, devamos pluralizar e usar outra preposição:

"compressão de imagem" -> "compressão em imagens", talvez?

Essa discussão é uma discussão que aparece aqui no SOPT, mas que, na verdade é um problema de tradução técnica. Outro dia recebemos no laboratório que trabalho um formulário de uma editora solicitando indicação dos especialistas na área sobre quais formas seriam as melhores para tradução de termos técnicos do português pro inglês.