# Pedido de substituição de tag: [editordetexto] para [editor-de-texto]

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, re-tag

Apesar de ainda não haver conclusão definitiva em [Precisamos de padronização para tags com mais de uma palavra?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/443), a discussão ali deixa claro que é preferível ter tags com separador entre as palavras (por exemplo, `android-studio` e não `androidstudio`).

Fui tentar resolver o caso de [editordetexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/editordetexto), substituindo a tag e o respectivo wiki, mas o sistema não deixou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que seria bom resolvermos esses casos o quanto antes, mas somente moderadores podem fazer esta alteração. Então fica registrado aqui o pedido.

Comment: Por moderador é a melhor solução. Alternativamente, pode apagar a atual em todas peguntas e no dia seguinte colocar a certa. Mas tem risco de esquecer e é gambi. Não é a única tag assim.