# Sinônimo de tag: ie8 para internet-explorer-8

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tags-sinônimas

Acredito que [ie8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie8) deveria ser sinônimo de [internet-explorer-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-8). A primeira tem sido mais usada, mas a última segue o padrão discutido em *[Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-arvore)* e *[Precisamos de padronização para tags com mais de uma palavra?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/443/precisamos-de-padronizacao-para-tags-com-mais-de-uma-palavra)*

Gabe?

Comment: Por mim tudo bem. Alguém discorda?

Comment: Por que alguém discordaria?

Answer (score 9):

Deve ser criado o sinónimo, e já que estamos a tratar do Internet Explorer, pode-se criar também o sinónimo para o Internet Explorer 9 que se encontra na mesma situação:

[ie8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie8) → [internet-explorer-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-8) ← [ie8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie8)

[ie9](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie9) → [internet-explorer-9](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-9) ← [ie9](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie9)

---

## Atualização:

À data desta atualização, os sinónimos já se encontram criados estando este assunto resolvido:

[image: Captura de Tela] [image: Captura de Tela]