# O que fazer se a tag para a minha pergunta não existe?

Tags: suporte, tags, proposta-para-faq

Se eu ainda não posso adicionar tags, como proceder? Se eu colocar outra tag, não estarei fazendo o certo, pois a postagem estará sendo direcionada a uma área que não a certa. 
Onde devo solicitar a inclusão dessa possível tag? Acho que todos os novatos assim como eu já tiveram ou têm essa dúvida.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [stackoverflow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) em Português

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deixe como um comentário na própria pergunta, ou peça aqui no meta. Assim um usuário com privilégio de criação de tags poderá avaliar se a tag é mesmo relevante/necessária ou não, e qual a sua melhor [forma](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/443/215). O requisito de reputação para se criar tags é para evitar que se crie tags desnecessárias ou que fujam demais dos padrões estabelecidos. Espera-se de que quem cria uma tag uma familiaridade maior com o site do que o seu simples uso casual.

Claro, esse sistema não é perfeito - por exemplo, para sugerir que uma tag se torne sinônimo de outra é necessário pelo menos 5 pontos em respostas **naquela tag**. Recentemente pensei em adicionar [clipboard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clipboard) como sinônimo a [área-de-transferência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a1rea-de-transfer%c3%aancia), mas percebi que não havia ninguém no site com privilégio suficiente para fazê-lo... (exceto moderadores, é claro) Mas com o tempo e o crescimento da comunidade esses problemas vão se resolvendo. Não é nem bom ter tags em excesso, creio eu.

Comment: Ah, sua resposta esclareceu muitas duvidas, e até explicou outras prováveis. Com o tempo acho que todas as tags mais necessárias serão adicionadas, não vamos ter que nos preocupar, caso tope com esse dilema mais alguma vez, já sei o que fazer. Não posso deixar de agradecer, obrigado.