# Tradução adequada para a tag "batch-file"

Tags: debate, tradução, tags

A tag [batch-file](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file), bem como a [batch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch) existem no SOEN para marcar as perguntas sobre ficheiros de *script* que contém comandos que são interpretados pela linha de comandos do Windows.

## Problema

Antes de criar esta tag, achei melhor vir aqui definir o nome da mesma de forma a evitar futura manutenção à tag e/ou perguntas relacionadas.

## Pergunta

Em Português, qual a tradução adequada para o nome desta tag mediante o que tem vindo a ser definido sobre as tags?

---

<sup>Debates a decorrer à data da criação desta pergunta:</sup>
 <sup>- [Precisamos de padronização para tags com mais de uma palavra?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/443/precisamos-de-padronizacao-para-tags-com-mais-de-uma-palavra)</sup>
 <sup>- [Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-arvore)</sup>
 <sup>- [Qual padrão devemos utilizar para criar tags?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/130/qual-padrao-devemos-utilizar-para-criar-tags)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

De forma a tentar resolver a questão de uma só vez, eu optaria por criar a tag *base* e os seus sinónimos:

### Tag *base*

Criar a tag [batch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch)

No SOEN, a [tag base que eles adotaram não é esta](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, mas para nós, a tradução da tag base por eles adaptada *pode variar* <sup>ler mais a baixo</sup>, pelo que para simplificar, sugiro esta como a tag *base*.

### Sinónimos da tag

Como pode ser visto a partir dos links que deixaste na pergunta, a tendência é para o uso de nomes cujas múltiplas palavras são separadas por hífen, pelo que os nomes dos sinónimos ficariam:

[ficheiro-batch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ficheiro-batch) [batch-script](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-script) [batch-ficheiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-ficheiro) [windows-batch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-batch) [dos-batch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos-batch)

Estou a sugerir a [batch-ficheiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-ficheiro) e a [ficheiro-batch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ficheiro-batch), pois a construção do nome vai depender muito se a pessoa que está a criar uma pergunta com uma destas tags está a pensar à *Inglesa* ou à Portuguesa:

[batch-ficheiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-ficheiro) Tradução à letra do SOEN

[ficheiro-batch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ficheiro-batch) Tradução para Português do nome no SOEN

Outro aspeto importante é que quando estamos a escrever o nome das tags, o sistema procura sugerir as que começam pelas letras já introduzidas, pelo que a palavra `batch` antes e depois da palavra `ficheiro` revelar-se-à proveitoso no futuro para evitar a criação de tags novas para assuntos que já contém tag.

**Nota:** Só estou a sugerir os sinónimos que me lembrei quando estava a pensar no assunto, no SOEN eles tem um pelotão inteiro deles :)

---

#### A desconsiderar

Também vejo que no SOEN existe a tag pluralizada [batch-files](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-files), mas não vejo um elevado número de utilizadores com a tendência para ficheiros-batch ou batch-ficheiros... por isso não recomendo a criação deste sinónimo pluralizado.

Comment: Sem falar que também usaremos *arquivo* como sinônimo para *ficheiro* em todos os lugares :) O sinônimo só pode ser criado quando ambas tags já existem. Em alguns casos eu acho que vale criar uma tag diferente para criar o sinônimo artificialmente, evitando futuros erros de uso. Acho que devemos tentar usar sinônimos tanto quanto possível, para equiparar a escrita em inglês, em português, em "brasileiro", no português invertido (estilo inglês), no plural, etc. Temos que ficar de olho para não deixar as tags virarem bagunça.

Comment: E em breve os usuário de alta reputação terão que começar ajudar colocar tags adequadas nas perguntas já que os novatos não poderão criar novas tags.

Comment: Em "brasileiro", usa-se "arquivo de lote" para batch file.